# Merge 2 element of same array into one in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hrg_lid] => 214291464161204318
            [pecon] => 0
            [col2pe] => Karam
            [col4pe] => 1
            [col6pe] => 2
            [col8pe] => 264
            [col9pe] => 42
            [col10pe] => 85
            [col11pe] => 2

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hrg_lid] => 707581464079555092
            [pecon] => 1
            [col2pe] => Dummy
            [col4pe] => 
            [col6pe] => 
            [col8pe] => 12
            [col9pe] => 0
            [col10pe] => 0
            [col11pe] => 2
            [col12pe] => 1
            [col13pe] => 1

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hrg_lid] => 707581464079555092
            [col5risk] => 2
            [col6risk] => 2
            [col7risk] => 1
            [col8risk] => 2
            [col9risk] => 1
            [col10risk] => 1
            [col11risk] => 2
        )
```

I want to merge those elements which has same **hrg_lid**. 
Expected Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hrg_lid] => 214291464161204318
            [pecon] => 0
            [col2pe] => Karam
            [col4pe] => 1
            [col6pe] => 2
            [col8pe] => 264
            [col9pe] => 42
            [col10pe] => 85
            [col11pe] => 2

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hrg_lid] => 707581464079555092
            [pecon] => 1
            [col2pe] => Dummy
            [col4pe] => 
            [col6pe] => 
            [col8pe] => 12
            [col9pe] => 0
            [col10pe] => 0
            [col11pe] => 2
            [col12pe] => 1
            [col13pe] => 1
            [col5risk] => 2
            [col6risk] => 2
            [col7risk] => 1
            [col8risk] => 2
            [col9risk] => 1
            [col10risk] => 1
            [col11risk] => 2

        )
```

I tried following code

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
       $finalArray[$value['hrg_lid']] = $value;

   }
```

but fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `hrg_lid` as array key - otherwise you have to check every element already in the output array for matches every time you add a new element:

```
$finalArray = array();

foreach($arr as $value) {
    $hrg_lid = $value['hrg_lid'];
    if (isset($finalArray[$hrg_lid])) {
        // merge if element with this $hrg_lid is already present
        $finalArray[$hrg_lid] = array_merge($finalArray[$hrg_lid], $value);
    } else {
        // save as new
        $finalArray[$hrg_lid] = $value;
    }
}
```

If you want to get normalized array keys, you can reset them afterwards:

```
$finalArray = array_values($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The hrg_lid value must be the key of the array, if you won't change the keys, Try this :

```
for($i=0; $i < count($arr);$i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j < count($finalArray);$j++)
    {
        if($arr[$i]['hrg_lid'] == $finalArray[$j]['hrg_lid'])
        {
             $finalArray[$j] = array_merge($finalArray[$j],$arr[$i]);
             break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try soomething like :

```
$finalArray = [];

foreach($arr as $singleArray) {
    $id = $singleArray['hrg_lid'];
    if (isset($finalArray[$id])) {
        $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray[$id], $singleArray);
    } else {
        $finalArray[] = $singleArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that :

```
$tmpArray = array();
$finalArray = array();

// We merge the arrays which have the same value in 'hrg_lid' col
foreach($source as $array){
    $key = $array['hrg_lid'];
    array_shift($array);
    if(array_key_exists($key, $tmpArray)){
        $tmpArray[$key] = array_merge($tmpArray[$key], $array);
    }else{
        $tmpArray[$key] = $array;
    }
}

// We build the final array
foreach($tmpArray as $key => $value){
    $finalArray[] = array_merge(array('hrg_lid' => $key), $value);
}
```